# How to define allocationSize and initialValue for all entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

On all my entities, I defined `allocationSize` and `initialValue` manually, just like this :

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQUENCE_ID", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

Is it possible to set these attributes globally for all my entities ?
If so, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [SequenceGenerator's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html):

> The scope of the generator name is global to the persistence unit
>   (across all generator types).

So you can define one at in package-info.java as stated in the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-identifier):

```
@GenericGenerators({
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "uuid2",
        strategy = "uuid2"
    )
})
package your.package;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerators;
```

Then you need to add you package to the SessionFactory Configuration:

```
configuration.addPackage("your.package");
```

And then you can reuse these common generators in all your entities:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

Comment: For each sequence generator you can define one configuration, but you still need the GeneratedValue on each entity.

Answer (score 2):

`Generator` and `GeneratedValue` are two different things. Once `Generator` is set (via annotation or xml) it is accessible for whole persistence unit. `GeneratedValue` describes how given `id` should be generated (in your case it points to one of the generators).

You cannot set `allocationSize` nor `initialValue` for all `Generators` in advance, but you can set it for one generator and use it for many entities.

Please also note that `Hibernate` has default value of 50 for `allocationSize`.